# a href not displaying link on page in python cgi

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have a list of links and some text stored in database. I wish to print the text using the corresponding links using `<a href`.

In a for loop, I tried to print the anchors this way :

```
for i in range(8):
    #print url_list[i], question[i]
    print "<a href=\"" + url_list[i] + "\">" + question[i] + "<\/a>" + "<br>"
```

The commented part prints the text but the second gives a blank page. This should print 8 links on the page.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: You escaped your end "a" tag, try "</a><br>" instead

Comment: When you say "blank page" do you mean after a web request or terminal execution? If it's a web requests, maybe you're not sending the browser the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: I am using `print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"`. The blank page is showed after full execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be wrong?

For one thing, `"<\/a>"` should be `"</a>"`.

For another, your python is incredibly difficult to read. Try:

```
print r'<a href="{0}">{1}</a><br>'.format(url_list[i], question[i])
```

or even:

```
for url, q in zip(url_list, question):
  print r'<a href="{0}">{1}</a><br>'.format(url, q)
```

Also note that if your URLs have special characters in them (such as space or ampersand), you will need to escape them:

```
import urllib
for url, q in zip(url_list, question):
  url = urllib.quote_plus(url)
  print r'<a href="{0}">{1}</a><br>'.format(url, q)
```

Comment: I don't know how, the second one started to work properly when I changed the extension from `.cgi` to `.py`.